# Why does the infinite union of a set of events informally imply "at least one event exists"?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Many times in probability books they have that $\bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty}A_k$ is interpreted as being that at least one $A_k$ occurs.

However, normally when I think of the union I think of it as keeping a single copy that occurs in each set. In a way, it almost seems that the infinite union is combining all unique items of $A_k$ together. Is there a way to reconcile these two ideas I have?

Comment: $x \in \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty}A_k$ **iff** there is at least one $A_k$ such that $x \in A_k$.

Answer (score 2):

if $P(A_k)=0$ for all $k$ then
$$
P(\bigcup_{k = 1}^{\infty}A_k)=0
$$
since a countable union of null sets is null. So if the probability of the second is positive, the probability of one of the firsts must be positive too.